The cursor is not printing any count even if there is record in table in Oracle Procedure
I have created a SP where I am running a logic to bring the V_SPANID_COUNT count but it is always showing 0 count even if there is some record say 10-20 records
Below is my SP..
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_NELENGTH_LESS_THAN_CMMAPPROVED AS 

V_ERRORS NVARCHAR2(3000);
V_SPANID_COUNT   NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

        FOR CUR_NE_DATA IN
        (
            SELECT COUNT(SPAN_LINK_ID) INTO V_SPANID_COUNT from CMP_PANINDIA_VIEW_AGING_UPD 
            WHERE NE_LENGTH < ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM
            AND CMM_APPROVED_DATE IS NOT NULL
            AND MISSING_ASBUILT = 0 and SPAN_TYPE <> 'FTTX'
            AND job_progress_flag = 1
        )
LOOP

          dbms_output.put_line('COUNT OF DATA: ' || V_SPANID_COUNT);
          
END LOOP;  

END PROC_NELENGTH_LESS_THAN_CMMAPPROVED;


As usual, @MT0 is correct.  If you actually tried to create this procedure, you'd get a syntax error because the INTO would have been unexpected.  It is very helpful to include the error message you're getting in the question.  Especially when you are not posting a reproducible test case.

@JustinCave Surprisingly, the OP's procedure does compile without errors fiddle; it just doesn't work as the INTO clause appears to get ignored so the DBMS_OUTPUT statement is just printing the default value for the variable.

@MT0 - Really??  Wow.  I've learned something today

Oracle not complaining has come up before - here and here, and probably other places but it's hard to search for...

Don't mix INTO and cursor loops. Use one or the other but not both:
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_NELENGTH_LESS_THAN_CMMAPPROVED AS 
  V_ERRORS NVARCHAR2(3000);
BEGIN
  FOR CUR_NE_DATA IN (
    SELECT COUNT(SPAN_LINK_ID) AS cnt
    FROM   CMP_PANINDIA_VIEW_AGING_UPD 
    WHERE  NE_LENGTH < ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM
    AND    CMM_APPROVED_DATE IS NOT NULL
    AND    MISSING_ASBUILT = 0
    and    SPAN_TYPE <> 'FTTX'
    AND    job_progress_flag = 1
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('COUNT OF DATA: ' || CUR_NE_DATA.cnt);
  END LOOP;  
END PROC_NELENGTH_LESS_THAN_CMMAPPROVED;

or:
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_NELENGTH_LESS_THAN_CMMAPPROVED AS 
  V_ERRORS NVARCHAR2(3000);
  V_SPANID_COUNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(SPAN_LINK_ID)
  INTO   V_SPANID_COUNT
  FROM   CMP_PANINDIA_VIEW_AGING_UPD 
  WHERE  NE_LENGTH < ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM
  AND    CMM_APPROVED_DATE IS NOT NULL
  AND    MISSING_ASBUILT = 0
  and    SPAN_TYPE <> 'FTTX'
  AND    job_progress_flag = 1;

  dbms_output.put_line('COUNT OF DATA: ' || V_SPANID_COUNT);
END PROC_NELENGTH_LESS_THAN_CMMAPPROVED;

fiddle
